# Non-singular involutive distribution

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold. A distribution $D$ on $M$ is an assignment of a subspace $D_m \subset T_mM$ for each $m\in M$. A vector field $X$ on M belongs to $D$ if $X_m \in D_m$, for all $m\in M$. A distribution $D$ is said to be involutive if $[X,Y]\in D$ for all $X,Y\in D$. A distribution $D$ is called non-singular if for all $m\in M$, there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $m$ such that the dimension of $D$ is constant on $U$.

Under which conditions is a non-singular distribution involutive?

Comment: These are independent conditions. Checking involutivity involves looking at derivatives of vector fields that span the distribution, while non-singularity does not involve any information about the derivatives. So in any case, one would not expect a simple relationship between them.

Comment: Obviously the Frobenius theorem holds for sufficiently smooth distributions: involutivity just when the tangent bundle of a foliation. I don't know of any result on involutivity which holds for rough distributions. I doubt if you can prove anything without some Sobolev or Hoelder condition on $D$.

Comment: Your definition should state some smoothness condtion on $X$, since otherwise $[X,Y]$ might be nowhere defined.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the Frobenius theorem holds for sufficiently smooth distributions: involutivity just when the tangent bundle of a foliation. The most recent results on generalizations of the Frobenius theorem to nonsmooth distributions appear, along with an extensive bibliography of a raft of similar generalizations, in:

[MR3530282](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3530282) Reviewed
Luzzatto, S.(I-ICTP); Türeli, S.(I-ICTP); War, K. M.(I-ICTP)
*[A Frobenius theorem for corank-1 continuous distributions in dimensions two and three](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5896).* (English summary)
**Internat. J. Math.** 27 (2016), no. 8, 1650061, 30 pp.
58A30